# Making buttons - <button> or <div>?

Tags: html

I'm wondering what html element to use for buttons on a web page - I'd like to style my 'buttons' like twitter does. For example:

http://twitter.com/twitter

the "more" button at the bottom of the tweet listing - is that a `<button>` element, or a `<div>` element? I'd like to know which to use. I think for either `<button>` or `<div>` we can supply rollover states and all that stuff to make it look pleasant?

Comment: I think this is not the right place for your question:
SO FAQ:"Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is 'designer', ask on Doctype."

Comment: The more button is a div with a link in it. If you are using firefox you could use firebug to find these things out easily. I highly recommend it. Also the web developer add on.

Comment: Also, if you're having issues telling what a particular element is, go get Firebug for Firefox. Don't do one more bit of CSS work till you do. You'll be very happy. (I think anyways)

Comment: According to Firebug, it's an `<a>`.  http://i132.photobucket.com/albums/q1/MiffTheFox/twitter_more_link.png

Comment: if <button>'s properties behaviors are enough for what you need then use button. if you require more designing, stick with divs. div's aren't necessarily wrong to be used as substitute for buttons. they are, afaik, more flexible and customizable.

Answer (score 132):

Don't use `<div>` tags to make clickable elements.  Use `<a>` or `<button>` elements.  This enables browsers with JavaScript disabled to interact with them as expected, in addition to a *host* of other benefits listed below.  Even if your functionality requires JavaScript and there is no reasonable default behaviour you can assign to an `<a>` or `<button>`, use it anyways - it conveys "clickable" semantics.

In general, choose the tag that most closely describes the *function* of its content, not the appearance of its content, and avoid unnecessary `<div>` tags lest your documents suffer from [divitis](http://csscreator.com/divitis).

Because "it requires JavaScript on the client" is usually rejected out of hand as a reason for doing *anything*, in 2023, here are a few examples of behavior you're breaking by choosing `<div>` over a `<button>`/`<a>` tag. Some of this functionality can be restored with specific additional work, but that is often overlooked, and again, this is *extra work* to achieve feature-parity with what you get by default when using the correct `<button>` or `<a>` element:

- Your `<div>` cannot be navigated to with the keyboard or by many accessibility devices, making your site fundamentally inaccessible to people who cannot easily use a mouse, or people who simply prefer a keyboard
- Your `<div>` is not surfaced as an interactive element by screen-reader software, again, making it inaccessible by people with vision impairments
- Your `<div>` doesn't show where it will take the user in the status bar of the browser, `<a>` does
- Your users cannot middle-click or ctrl-click your `<div>` to open the link in a new tab, or a new window, the way they can with `<a>`
- Search engines cannot (easily) follow your `<div>` from page to page to index your content
- It's generally a given that you will apply a significant amount of styling to make your `<div>` *look* like a button or anchor tag, but again: Extra work to achieve feature-parity.

In short, it *unambiguously good* to use `<a>` or `<button>` over `<div>`: It costs you nothing, with no downside, and is important for a non-zero number of your users. Nobody has ever said "Oh good, this element is a div, not a button", however, *lots* of people say "Oh no, this element is a div when it should have been an anchor tag, now I can't use this site".

Comment: Buttons are notoriously harder to style/position in a cross browser way than divs.  Also, if the 'button' is just triggering some JS, then I don't see the problem with it being div.

Comment: @UpTheCreek A `<div>` doesn't communicate clickability to a screen reader and adds no semantic value to a document. They're fundamentally inaccessable. At the very least you should be using `<a>` tags which are every bit as styleable as `<div>` tags, but carry clickable semantics. There is never a good reason to choose a `<div>` over and `<a>` for a clickable UI element.

Comment: @UpTheCreek I use [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) for "clicking" links. It doesn't work for div-clicks. Having a anchor does not rid you of any style possibility (`display:block` and it behaves like a div) and it adds semantics.

Comment: as mentioned on MSO ...  
Isn't this situation : having interactive ("clickable") elements semantically included in list form within other "clickable" elements--in this case, a `ul` with clickable `li` elements that is presented after clicking the `a` element (the little cog icon) -- the main motivation of the totally unimplemented menu element (now grasping for adoption in the HTML 5.1 draft)? http://w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-menu-element

Comment: Use `<a>`. Button is not the solution. Example: You have a form with `<button>add new line</button>` and `<button>submit</button>`. When you press Enter you fire add new line and not submit. When I press Enter I expect submit.

Comment: Its also worth mention <a> tag does not require an href, if you are worried about navigation.

Comment: @user229044 "There is never a good reason to choose a <div> over and <a>" -- If i need an `<a>` nested inside an `<a>`, that's not permitted. But a `div` can do that.

Comment: @AntiCZ [It should be `<button type="input">`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 7):

The "more" button on Twitter is an `<a>` with a background-image, CSS3 rounded corners, and a border.  Here's the complete CSS (elem is `<a class="more round">`):

```css
 .more {
      outline: none;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 6px 0;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
      border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
      background-color: #fff;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-position: left top;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      height: 22px;
      line-height: 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 6px;
      background-image: url('/images/more.gif');
    }
    
    .more:hover {
      border: 1px solid #bbb;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-position: left -78px;
    }
    
    .more:active {
      color: #666;
      background-position: left -38px;
    }
    
    .round {
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="more round">Sample Button</a>
```

You should use `<a>` or `<button>`, not `<div>`.

Comment: an anchor with an href attribute will trigger page reload. Without an href, it is not "tabable", and it still does not carry the button semantic. `<a role="button" tabindex="0"></a>` does all that.

Answer (score 3):

In general you want to use `<a>` for navigation and `<button>` for some action that takes place on that screen.

The best reason I can think of to prefer a `<button>` or `<a>` tag to `<anything-else>` is that during testing, it makes it easier to locate the actionable items. I use [Capybara and Rspec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for example, and the method `click_on` works a lot more reliably when it refers to a `<button>`, the same with the method `click_link` and `<a>`.

The other reasons given here are also good: semantics, screen readers, etc.

Pragmatically, your audience will decide if every single element on your page is a really fancy `<div>` or if you want to play nice with the rest of the web dev ecosystem. It may simply depend on whether your audience all uses X browser or not.

One gotcha: Since a `<button>` could submit a form or `<a>` take you to another page, you have to make sure to prevent those default actions. In the JavaScript function that handles the click, you have to specify that it only does the action you program.

```
function onClickEvent(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  // What you want to do instead
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use an `a` tag instead of `button`. My reasoning involves compatibility issues with older version of IE (IE6 hates the `button` tag).

[<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-typebutton-which-to-use)

Comment: IE6 must die for the Web to move on. Don't use compatibility with IE6 as a justification for an html design choice. http://www.ie6nomore.com/

Comment: Yea but in general input and button elements always have consistency issues when referring to css styling.

Comment: especially nowadays, the benefits far outweigh the negatives

Answer (score -4):

I'd suggest `<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />` with a css style to give the appearance that you're looking for.

Comment: that's very bad practice except in very specific cases