# How to increase the clickable area of a <a> tag button?

Tags: css, button, html, clickable

I have learnt from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777256/making-buttons-button-or-div/2777280#comment14500094_2777280) that always use `<a>` tags or `<button>` tags to make button. Now I'm trying to use `<a>` tag. My question is: is there any way to increase the  tag clickable area? Say I'm using `<a>` in a div box. I want the whole div box to become a button. Can I change the  clicking area to the whole div box?
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[@t1m0thy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20327676/1225328) is more elegant than mine. It's better to follow his advice.

Also, nice link proposed by [@aldemarcalazans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4941815/aldemarcalazans) in the comments: https://davidwalsh.name/html5-buttons.

---

**Original answer:**

Use `<a />` when you need a link (the *a* of *anchor*). Use `<button />` when you need a button.

That said, if you really need to expand an `<a />`, add the CSS attribute `display: block;` on it. You'll then be able to specify a width and/or a height (i.e. as if it were a `<div />`).

Comment: This works perfectly, and your answer came in light speed. Your rock! Thank you so much.

Comment: If you worry about semantics,t1m0thy's answer seems to be the right choice. See: https://davidwalsh.name/html5-buttons

Comment: Facebook also uses this approach to expand the tap target of the links in the navigation for their mobile web app. I prefer this approach, much more readable IMO.  "// make tap target of link bigger"

Comment: Remember to make `display:block` both the container of the `<a />` and also the `<a />`. Then you should use `padding` for the `<a />`, not for the container of the `<a />`.

Comment: Probably going to upset a lot of developers here, but need to add that a lot of devs are limited by their comps and cannot make this change. A <button> needs to LOOK like a button in the UI if you use <button>, just as <a> needs to look like a link under WCAG. Aside from Structure, Contrast, and Touch Area, this is the most common accessibility UI mis-implementation. So please either ask for a design change, or find a more correct way for your comps. (I know navbars are sort of weird, but in general, I mean.)

Answer (score 212):

To increase the area of a text link you can use the following css;

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: -2em;
}
```

```html
<a href="">An anchor element</a>
```

- Display: inline-block is required so that margins and padding can be set
- Position needs to be relative so that...
- z-index can be used to make the clickable area stay on top of any text that follows.
- The padding increases the area that can be clicked
- The negative margin keeps the flow of surrounding text as it should be (beware of over lapping links)

Comment: this is the real answer on *how to increase clickable area of a tag button*

Comment: This was the first recipe I've found that worked with an icon next to it, thanks.  However I had to change: `padding: 0 2em; margin: 0 -2em;` to prevent the clickable area from being pushed down.

Comment: I also needed to set `box-sizing: content-box` which was reset to `border-box` by bootstrap

Comment: This is a negative margin in all 4 directions?

Comment: The z-index does not seem to be necessary in Chrome? Maybe in other browsers?

Comment: worked like a charm. z-index is necessary for making it browser compatible.

Answer (score 22):

Yes you can if you are using **HTML5**, this code is **valid** not otherwise:

```
<a href="#foo"><div>.......</div></a>
```

If you are not using HTML5, you can make your link `block`:

```css
#link {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#foo" id="link">Click Here</a>
```

Notice that you can apply `width`, `height` only after making your link block level element.

Answer (score 17):

For me the padding solution wasn't good, as I was using border on the button, and would've been hard to modify the markup to create an overlay for the touch area.

So I just used the :before pseudo element and created an overlay, which was perfect in my case, as the click event propagated the same way.

```css
button.my-button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  top: -6px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="my-button">A button</button>
```

Note: Make sure you have `position:relative` on the parent element.

Comment: This is the best solution, deserves the check. You can also add `z-index` in case anything overlaps the touch area

Comment: This answer worked for me. However I had to add `position: relative;` to the parent element, otherwise the `::before` pseudo element would change position as by layout would move (there are animations on the page).

Comment: Yes, that is expacted behavior. I added a note to my answer.

Comment: or you just set the width and height to 100%. worked for me. thanks! button.my-button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
} and the .button should be position: relative

Answer (score 10):

Just make the anchor `display: block` and `width/height: 100%`. Eg:

```
.button a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mHTa/

Answer (score 10):

add `padding` to the CSS class of anchor tag. If required, add `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`,... individually according to the clickable area you want. It worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using HTML 5, i.e. the doctype

```
<!doctype html>
```

then you can just use [block-level links](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/).

```
<a href="google.com">
  <div class="hello">
    ..
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You might try using display: block or display: inline-block. A nice tutorial can be found here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Answer (score 3):

Provide more **left,Bottom,right and top** space. This will have more clickable/touchable area of anchor tag for easy click...

**Remember:**  this may have negative effects as well

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 10px !important;
  padding: 0px 1px !important;
  margin-right: 3px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}

a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: 40;
}
```

```html
<a href="">An anchor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CSS` position property and set top, right, bottom and left to 0. Set z-index if needed.

In my case, I used text-indent because I don’t want to show link "text", but if you want to show link "text", just don't use text-indent

```css
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-indent: -99999px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to the contributors to the answers here, it pointed me in the right direction.

For the Bootstrap4 users out there, this worked for me.  Sets the a link (tap target) to correct size to pass the Lighthouse Site Audit on mobiles.

```
    <span class="small">
         <a class="d-inline position-relative p-3 m-n3" style="z-index: 1;" href="/AdvancedSearch" title="Advanced Site Search using extra optional filters">Advanced Site Search</a>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

the simple way I found out:
add a **"li"** tag on the right side of an **"a"** tag List item

```
<li></span><a><span id="expand1"></span></a></li>
```

On CSS file create this below:

```
#expand1 {
 padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I've found is using `::before` as I didn't wanted to alter and potentially complicate the `HTML`. Here is an example:

```css
    // the parent element
    .chevron {
        position: relative;
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;
        border-radius: 18px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    // the background covers only 36px as of the parent
    .chevron:hover {
        background: #F1FBFE;
    }
    
    // the invisible "touch area"
    .chevron::before {
        position: absolute;
        width: 48px;
        height: 48px;
        top: -6px; // half of parent's height
        content: '';
    }
```

Other properties such as `left`, `cursor`, `z-index` are not necessary. Specifically `cursor` is inherited from the parent as the `pseudo-element` lays under the parent (even though stretches further).

Bellow image show how the mouse has not yet entered the parent element but it will still trigger `:hover` (adding `background`) and `cursor: pointer`.

[image: Chevron (increased hit-area) (zoomed-in for visibility)]

> Note: I haven't tested this for selectable contents.

Answer (score 0):

This also work to increase anchor tag clickable area which is stated by **Fitts's Law: The Importance of Size and Distance in UI Design**

```
a {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}

a:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: 40;
}
a:active{
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you have class **button** you can do the following:

```
.button {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .button::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a situation where adding extra padding is problematic, try this:

```
a { 
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative:
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```