# To create a bunch of tile-style buttons, should I use <button>, <span> or just <div>?

Tags: html, css

To create a bunch of tile-style buttons like the one shown below,

[image]

should I use ,  or just ?

Comment: Use `<button>`. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2777280/11774872

Comment: Yes. They are buttons, so use `<button>`.

Comment: they are buttons so just use `<button>`

Comment: they are buttons, so use buttons