# CSS sliding-window rounded-corner buttons: how to avoid the "dead" area on right side of "window"?

Tags: html, css

The html / CSS I've been using is below.

When the cursor is over .buttonR, there is no :hover effect, nor does it properly submit when clicked.  There is a 6-pixel dead area on that right side that I'm trying to get around.  Any suggestions?  Is there a flaw in my original approach at achieving rounded-corner buttons?

Thanks.

```
    <span class="buttonR">
<input type="submit" id="updateReview" class="buttonL" value="Save changes" />
    </span>

.buttonL
{
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0px 0px 8px 6px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('../Images/buttonL.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 6px;
}

.buttonR
{
    float: left;
    padding-right: 6px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background: url('../Images/buttonR.gif') no-repeat scroll top right;
    margin: 0px 6px 0px 0px;
}
```

**Update:**

So I've managed to solve the "dead area" problem using a variation of zzzz's answer:

```
<button type="submit" class="buttonR">
  <span class="buttonL">Save Changes</span>
</button>
```

but for the life of me, I cannot get a consistent vertical alignment between browsers.  Chrome and IE are aligned, while Firefox will have a 2 pixel variance between .buttonL and .buttonR.

I've heard of variances between browsers, but thought for sure there was a workaround somewhere.  I can't find it... damnation this is frustrating.

**Update #2**

Here's what I wound up with after an hour of messing with the padding and margins:

[image]

Comment: The flaw is that the 6px dead area is the padding on your span. If your button text isn't going to change, consider using a static image background.

Comment: Yeah, that was the whole reason behind using two images, to give it the dynamic-width capability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to check if it works in IE etc:

```
<button type="submit" class="buttonR">
  <span class="buttonL">Save Changes</span>
</button>
```

I try to avoid the button element, but it may be of help to you in this case.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try it right away.  Out of curiosity, why do you try to avoid the button element?  Do you avoid the custom buttons altogether, or do you have another method?

Comment: I think you meant to say, "Why do you try to avoid the `<input>` element?"  Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-typebutton-which-to-use

Comment: Styling the button elements can be really finicky cross-browser. There are some JavaScript driven solutions involving anchor tags. Mostly I try to avoid needing an image for a button.

Rounded corners can be done with border-radius...if you don't care about IE.

Comment: @JohnB no, I avoid the <button> element. the <input> element works a little nicer cross-browser.

Comment: Possibly due to exactly what you're talking about, I can't get the two sides to match up vertically.  Any ideas?

Comment: @zzzzBov: but I'm saying that's what PT meant to ask you.

Comment: @JohnB he asked the right question and I answered his question, no correction necessary. I'm not talking about the button type. I'm talking about the <button> element on the whole.

Comment: I wound up with some crazy, inconsistent padding numbers, but I finally got a variation of this to work.  I hate CSS.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

html:

```
<div class="cornerLeft"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="updateReview" class="buttonL" value="Save changes" />
<div class="cornerRight"></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

css:

```
 .cornerLeft, .cornerRight, .buttonL{
    float:left;
}
.cornerLeft{
    width:10px;/*the width of the left corner*/
    height:26px;
    background:#ffa;/*put url to image leftCorner*/
}
.cornerRight{
    width:10px;/*the width of the right corner*/
    height:26px;
    background:#ffa;/*put url to image rightCorner*/
}
.buttonL
{
    display:block;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0px 6px 8px 6px;
    background-color: none;
    border:none;/*set to none*/
    background-image: url('../Images/buttonL.gif') no-repeat;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.buttonL:hover{
    background-image:url();/*enter your path here*/
    background:#ccc;/*set to none*/
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
    float:none;
}
```

see it in action http://jsfiddle.net/2E2UJ/1/  New link!

You will need to subtract the padding from left and right from the total width of the image you use as background of the button.

Comment: This won't be dynamic width, though.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this latest one has a dead area on both sides now, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HW5Gf/)

*HTML*

```
<span class="buttonR">
<input type="submit" id="updateReview" class="buttonL" value="Save changes" />
</span>
```

*CSS*

```
.buttonL, .buttonR
{
  height: 26px;
}
.buttonL
{
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0px 27px;
  background: transparent url('http://imgur.com/gGIYJ.png') no-repeat -2px left;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left; 6px;
}
.buttonR
{
  padding: 0px;
  background:transparent url('http://imgur.com/JnSVn.png') no-repeat -3px right;
}
.buttonR:hover{
  background-color:black;
}
.buttonL:hover{
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: I think there might be something wrong with the background line's format.

Comment: It has 2 different images...  so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Also, I ripped out a lot of superfluous CSS from your code, something you still might want to consider even if you use `<button>`.  Also, a screenshot would be very helpful in understanding what you are trying to do here.  Lastly, you asked how you can get cross browser compatibility: `[if IE]` for Internet Explorer (in HTML), `@-moz-document url-prefix()` for Firefox (in CSS), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the browser tip.  I posted the finished image.