# Difference between button and input?

Tags: html, forms, button, input, submit

Are there any major differences between `<button type="button" name="theButton">SUBMIT</button>` and `<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="theButton" />`

Also, can you use `<button type="submit" name="theButton">SUBMIT</button>`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here's a page](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/) describing the differences (basically you can put html into a `<button></button>`

[And an other page](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE) describing why people avoid `<button></button>` (Hint: IE6)

Reference: [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-typebutton-which-to-use)

Also have a look at this [slideshow about button](http://nickcowie.com/presentation/s5-button.html).

Answer (score 2):

> `<button type="button" name="theButton">SUBMIT</button>`

Won't submit a form (bugs in some browsers aside)

> `<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" name="theButton" />`

Will submit a form.

> Also, can you use `<button type="submit" name="theButton">SUBMIT</button>`?

Will submit a form, but doesn't have a value (bugs in IE aside)

Comment: Regarding button with type submit, the bug is in IE7 and less that set the inner HTML of the button as its value.. fixed in IE8.