# ASP.net c# button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, onclick, buttonclick

Given:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnNext">Next &gt;</button>
```

I need in my code behind the have the onclick event, but the onclick event in this case refers to clientonclick, I have to use the button HTML tag not ASP:button because ASP:Button renders as input which doesn't work with  my CSS....

Any ideas?

**For everyone saying change my CSS, here it is:**

```
input[type=button], button {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    outline-width: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
        inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
        inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out,
        color 0.2s ease-in-out,
        -webkit-box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out,
        color 0.2s ease-in-out,
        -moz-box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out,
        color 0.2s ease-in-out,
        box-shadow 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
        color-stop(0.0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)),
        color-stop(0.01, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)),
        color-stop(0.4, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)),
        color-stop(0.4, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)),
        color-stop(1.0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) 0%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 40%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) 40%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px -1px 0px;
}
input[type=button]:hover, input[type=button]:focus, button:hover, button:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9),
        inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9),
        inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
}
input[type=button]:active, button:active {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.0s;
}
```

If I assign this to an input it doesn't show all the effects.

Comment: You can't use CSSClass in your ASP button to define your CSS?

Comment: See edit, not all effects work unless it's styled to a button element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Change your CSS** - the problem isn't with asp.net but its with your stylesheet.  Its really not that hard to stick 'input' after 'button' in your stylesheet

Comment: The css I'm using doesn't work on input elements, only the button element.

Comment: Look at edit, a lot of those CSS effects don't work with a <input> tag

Comment: That looks like a lot of nasty CSS, what does it actually do? Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use button seems to have a few problems of its own.  Why go against the flow?  Input is the way to go.

Comment: You are right, with much less CSS and <asp:button> I can style it 90% of what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The `<button>` element will be translated into an [HtmlButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.aspx) instance in your code-behind. That class exposes a server-side [ServerClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.serverclick.aspx) event that you can use for your purposes:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnNext"
    OnServerClick="btnNext_Click">Next &gt;</button>

protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the click event...
}
```