# Different Ways of creating Buttons in DOJO Framework

Tags: dojo

Hi ,  i found these two ways  for creating  Button in DOJO Framework

```
<input id="cb" dojotype="dijit.form.Button" name="developer" type="Button" />

<button dojoType="Button" widgetId="helloButton" onClick="helloPressed();">Hello World!</button>
```

Please tell me if there is any difference  between these two ways of creating buttons in DOJO ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Dojo's dijit.form.Button documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/Button.html), the difference is in the html tag underlying dojo's widget. Here [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use) there is an interesting discussion about html button vs html input with type=button.

The main difference is that the second choice lets you write html content between tags.