# why gmail buttons is "div" tag and not "button" tag?

Tags: html, css, gmail

Why gmail buttons is "div" tag and not "button" tag?

The gmail button code from chrome firebug:

```
<div id=":or" class="T-I J-J5-Ji ar7 T-I-ax7 L3 T-I-JO" role="button" tabindex="0" aria-expanded="false" style="-webkit-user-select: none; " aria-haspopup="true">
 <span class="Ykrj7b">More</span>
 <div class="G-asx T-I-J3 J-J5-Ji"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance,
Yosef

Comment: Because the Google developers decided to use DIV tags instead of buttons.

Comment: because the rendering of `div` and `span` elements are much faster than OS dependent controlls

Comment: @haynar do you have a source for that?

Comment: no, but I believe that it's easier to render elements that are not OS dependent

Comment: Remembering what all those classes do must be a nightmare.

Comment: I'm sure there's some kind of automatism behind those class names.

Comment: @haynar: Why would a browser's layout engine render things faster than native OS code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume its Google going to insane depths over performance, as behind the scenes the `button` element has one of the longer trips through the WebKit stack.

[As shown in this video by Alex Russell](http://ontwik.com/javascript/txjs-2011-a9-alex-russell-life-of-a-button-element/).

Answer (score 5):

Most likely for compatibility.

Internet Explorer 6 and 7 seem to be adding their own [padding to button elements](http://www.creativespirits.com.au/treasurechest/too-much-padding-on-buttons-in-IE.html). Also, there seem to be width issues with button elements in those browsers [when applying styles to them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use).

Comment: I wouldn't of thought it was this, as Google only support IE8+ at present (http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6557) and indeed tend to go down the line of "upgrade your browser" to users of non-standards-compliant browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Google is famous for this. They use tables in a lot of their layouts too.

Does it really matter how they do it? Gmail seems to be pretty successful despite the fact that this is not the way the W3C says it should be done.