# Getting the HTML5 'button' tag to work across browsers

Tags: html, button

I am currently working on a university project, using HTML5.
I have been writing all my code using the button tag throughout. 
I have been testing the site using chrome, however, have just noticed that although the buttons appear in IE and Firefox, they do not function.

Is there a way to get around this? Or does the button tag just not work in these browsers?

This is the code which works perfectly well in chrome, but not other browsers.

```
<div class="option" id="question1" style="display:none">
<p> Which way do you think the criminals have fled?</p>
<p>Up the Stairs <button class="arrow" id="stairs"><a href="upstairs.html"><img src="images/arrow.png" width="15" height="15"/></a></button></p>
<p>Down the Alley <button class="arrow" id="alley"><a href="alley.html"><img src="images/arrow.png" width="15" height="15"/></a></button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be supported by IE and Firefox, can you provide a code fragment of what is not working? Also, what versions of IE and Firefox?

Comment: The button tag has been there for quite a while, it's pre-HTML5 standards.

Comment: Much has been said about this in the past. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use

Comment: Without a link or jsfiddle, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker - Your link is three years old and some of the links in that article don't work or refer to six-year old articles.

Comment: I have edited the question and added code which works fine in Chrome, but not other browsers

Comment: @Rob Valid, but the point is people have been discussing the use of buttons for a long time. As this is a university project I just wanted to give some idea as to how to find resources.

Comment: @MattMurphy, was my answer helpful? If so, could you click accept? See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask. If not, could you give some feedback so I, or someone else, can provide a better answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `button` element cannot have interactive descendants. Ergo, you cannot have an `a` tag as a child of the `button` element. Simply remove the `a` tag from the `button`, and change your code as necessary.

For more information, read up on the [`button` Element in the HTML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element).

## Example

```
<div class="option" id="question1" style="display:none;">
<p>Which way do you think the criminals have fled?</p>
<p>Up the Stairs <button class="arrow" id="stairs"><img src="images/arrow.png" width="15" height="15"></button></p>
<p>Down the Alley <button class="arrow" id="alley"><img src="images/arrow.png" width="15" height="15"></button></p>
</div>
```