# How to set the height of a button (input-element) on webkit browsers?

Tags: css, button

On my Mac with webkit-browsers (Safari and Chrome, current version) I can't set the height of an input-element.

```
<input type="button" style="height:200px;" value="Hello World!">​
```

won't work.

jQuerys `$('input').css('height','200px');​` won't work either.

http://jsfiddle.net/XmS6m/

Though setting the width is possible, either with style-attribute or with jQuery.

What is the reason for this inconsistency? And what is a possible solution?

Comment: On Win 7 versions of Safari and Chrome, the height takes effect when set in CSS (using the jsfiddle; pure CSS is enough, and so if the jQuery code alone). So this might be a Mac specialty (perhaps it has a special default value for `-webkit-appearance` for the button?), or maybe even an installation-specific issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Display inline-block does nothing, as inputs already have that display set by default. Add `border:none`. When you do so, it starts behaving like you want it to. Here's the fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/XmS6m/1/

Comment: or add whichever border you want.

Comment: This is a great tip, thanks! I'm new to CSS and have been searching for a solution to this for a while.  What does border:none accomplish?

Comment: argh! with border:none it doesn't actually look like a button! @JOPLOmacedo How do I add a border which looks like the default button appearance?

Comment: Instead of an <input type='button' />, you could use a button element <button></button>, which lets you change it's height, without requiring changes to the border property. If you're interested in the difference between the two elements (not much), here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use

Answer (score 2):

Button is an inline-level element. You need to change that to `block` or `inline-block`:

```css
#my_button { display: inline-block; height: 200px; }
```

**[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2909184)**

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for me. Anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: How does it not fix your problem? What do you have? Does my example work for you? Please don't just leave comments such as "it doesn't work" without explaining!

Comment: On my Mac your "Live example" won't adjust the height of the <input type="button">. Only the one of the <button>. Tested with Safari 5.1.7 and Chrome 19.

Comment: On my Mac, the left-hand button is tall. The right hand button shows no change in height.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `box-sizing` property to `content-box`:

```
.my-button {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also increase the font-size of the button to enlarge it.

Comment: Had to do that because inline-block was not working within table