# javascript change height based on element's height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set the height of an element equal to a div's height which height changes based on the elements inside it

I made this javascript code but it doesn't work.

What is wrong with it?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mar1/sne40vh1/)

HTML

```
<div id="a" onclick="changeHeight();">
</div>
<div id="button">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function changeHeight() {
var divHeight = $("#a").height();
document.getElementById('button').style.height = divHeight;
}
```

CSS

```
#a{width:300px;height:100px;background-color:black;}
#button{width:300px;background-color:green;}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976700/how-to-set-the-height-of-an-button-input-element-on-webkit-browsers

Comment: Your fiddle first throws an error that `changeHeight` is not defined when the element is clicked - that because you embedded the script code in the fiddle on load, you need to place it in the head. And then the next error is of course about `$`, because you neglected to actually embed jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sne40vh1/3/

The main problem was that you were trying to set the height of `#button` without a unit of measurement (jQuery's .height method returns only a value, no measurement) so when you were trying to set the style in the vanilla JavaScript, which requires a unit of measurement, it was failing (so in this case it would've needed '300px' but you were just giving it '300'.

I've changed it here to have a global function (which isn't recommended, I only did this for the fiddle to work) and changed the way you were setting the height of `#button` to match the way you were getting the height of `#a`:

HTML:

```
<div id="a" onclick="changeHeight()"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#a{width:300px;height:100px;background-color:black;}
#button{width:300px;background-color:green;}
```

JS:

```
changeHeight = function() {
  var divHeight = $("#a").height();
  $('#button').height(divHeight);
}
```

Feel free to compare what i've done with what you had in the first place in order to see my changes better.

Answer (score 1):

Do concatenate with `'px'`(Unit)

```js
function changeHeight() {
  var divHeight = $("#a").height();
  document.getElementById('button').style.height = divHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
#a {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
#button {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" onclick="changeHeight();"></div>
<div id="button"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you mixing jQuery and vanilla Js?
I wrote it completely with jQuery and it looks like it's working:

```js
function changeHeight() {
  var divHeight = $("#a").height();
  $('#button').height(divHeight);
}
```

```css
#a{width:300px;height:100px;background-color:black;}
#button{width:300px;background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" onclick="changeHeight();">
</div>
<div id="button">
</div>
```