# Make button onclick call a function instead of form action

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a JavaScript function to be called by my `button.onclick()` event, but the function is not called. Instead, my form action is performed.

HTML:

```
<form id = "Documents" action="Uploaded.php">
<input type="submit" id="Remove1" name="Remove[1]" value="Remove first" onclick="return Remove('Remove1');">
<input type="submit" id="Remove2" name="Remove[2]" value="Remove second" onclick=" return Remove('Remove2');">
</form>
```

Updated JavaScript:

```
function Remove(currentDoc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Removemsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/remove.php?Doc="+currentDoc,true);
xmlhttp.send();

    return false;
}
```

It calls `uploaded.php` rather than my `remove.php`. But I already defined my `onclick` function to call `remove.php`. Kindly advise.

Comment: Your JS is not valid: 3 `{` and 5 `}`. I think there is a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a `return false;` statement to `function remove()` for preventing form submission.

And also your `onclick="Remove()"` should be `onclick="return Remove();"`

Your JS code is also errorful

```
function Remove(currentDoc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Removemsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/remove.php?Doc="+currentDoc,true);
xmlhttp.send();

    return false;
}
```

Comment: If you mean adding a `return false` at the end of Remove() function body, it is not correct. Plus this, the event handler should change in this way: `onclick="return Remove('Remove1')"`

Comment: added but still it auto download uploaded.php rather than calling out remove.

Comment: my braces is abit messy, so sorry. it works but the Removemsg doesnt response out. It should be <span id= "Removemsg"></span>

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a submit button it will by default submit the form to the url in the action attribute.

In order to prevent it you need to return false at the end of your function:

```
function Remove(currentDoc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("Removemsg").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","functions/remove.php?Doc="+currentDoc,true);
xmlhttp.send();

return false;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work because it is like this:
`onclick="false"`
but the correct is:
`onclick="return false"`

Answer (score 1):

Use `<input type="button" />` instead of `<input type="submit" />` to prevent form submittion

Comment: Are you having a valid `HTML` I doubt on this `name="Remove[1]"`, usage of [] in name is not valid I guess.

Comment: even if i remove[1],it still doesn't call out. Strange :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<input type="submit" ... />` to generate a button, you could also use the `<button>` tag ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button))

```
<button type="button" id="Remove1" name="Remove[1]" onclick="Remove('Remove1')">Remove first</button>
```

This will generate a button. Through setting `type="button"` you prevent the default (`type="submit"`), which would trigger the form to submit.

Comment: I already define something for my <button> so i wont want to use that again.

Comment: [`<button>` vs. `<input type=“button” />`. Which to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/469059/1169798)

Answer (score 1):

when you click a submit button, it's quite natural that it submits the form. if you want to prevent this, you should return false at your event handler. note that returning false at the end of your remove function is not sufficient, you should write something like this:

```
<input type="submit" id="Remove1" name="Remove[1]" value="Remove first" onclick="return Remove('Remove1')">
```

and your remove function should return false.
also notice that there is a semantic error in your ajax coding. you should set onReadyStateChange after calling open() function of xmlhttp object. visit [here](http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/33024/1954) for more info

Comment: Tried but it doesnt call out my Remove function even though i have change t alert('this');

Comment: does it prevent form from submission?

Comment: It should call your function as well. Maybe you have a javascript fatal error somewhere which causes the function to be *undefined*. try to debug and find out whether the function is defined properly and works or not. Replace the whole of function's body, with an `alert(1);` and check again.

Comment: tried :( and also tried to debug crtl+shift+i for errors. But no errors given.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using JavaScript, then there is not need to use a `<form>`.

Comment: Your answer is not understandable!