# Cannot read property 'show' of undefined React js

Tags: reactjs

I'm using [SkyLight](http://marcio.github.io/react-skylight/) react component to make modal dialog. The problem that I'm trying to solve is how to show different content in modal dialog using only one button.

```
<a className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={() => {
   this.setState({
     features: plan.features
       })
      this.dialog.show()
   }}>Features</a>
```

The content that I want to show is `Array`.

For example: `features:["Feature 1", "Feature 2"]`

I'm keeping that features in `state` an show them on click using map looping.

```
<SkyLight hideOnOverlayClicked ref={ref => this.dialog = ref} title="Hi, I'm a simple modal">
  {
   this.state.features.map((feature)=>{
     <h4>{feature}</h4>
    })

      }
  </SkyLight>
```

When I click that button I have this error: **Cannot read property 'show' of undefined**

Any ideas how to solve this?\

Thanks

Comment: You should include enough code so that we can reproduce your issue. [mcve]

Comment: Unrellated to the question, but you should use a <button> instead of a <a> for modals https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647758/what-is-the-difference-between-button-onclick-and-a-href-onclick -- You should include more code if you want help on your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probably is that you are missing the `ref Creation` on your constructor.

```
class ParentComponentForModal extends Component{
    constructor(){
         // rest of your constructor.
         this.dialog = React.createRef();
    }
    //....rest of your code
}
```

and then change your component to have `ref={this.dialog}` instead of `ref={ref => this.dialog = ref}`

```
<SkyLight hideOnOverlayClicked ref={this.dialog} .....
```

adding a [working sample on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/62wjzrxjvw)

Comment: After I change this I get this error _react2.default.createRef is not a function

Comment: @Devmasta version of react being used?

Comment: I'm using 15.4.2 version

Comment: @Devmasta I added a working codesandbox.
I think your issue is not from react.