# What is the difference between <a href>, <div onclick>, and <button>?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

It seems there isn't much difference between `<a href>` and `<button>` from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647758/what-is-the-difference-between-button-onclick-and-a-href-onclick), but is it also fine to use `<div onclick>` ?

Comment: onclick on all tags are same

Comment: It depends on the case, but generally not, since without further changes, it won’t be focusable/activatable with a keyboard and accessibility tools like screen readers won’t call it out as a button. Better to restyle a real `<button>` if you want a button. (So, please specify in the question if you want a button.)

Answer (score 1):

Roughly,

`<a href>` by default has a click handler that parses the URL and decides on the right sort of action; for HTTP(S) URLs, it will dispatch a HTTP(S) request and replace the `window.location` with the new URL, and also correctly handle `History`. It also has other handlers associated with other events, not just `click`.

`<button type="submit">` by default has a `click` handler that finds out where a form is supposed to be submitted to, constructs the URL in case of a GET method or a request body in case of a POST method, then does the same thing as above.

`<... onclick="...">` will invoke the JavaScript code in the `onclick` attribute if the element is dispatched a `click` event. This code can do whatever it wants, including (but not limited to) simulating any of the above's response to a click — but you will have to write it yourself. If you would want to simulate everything the above ones do, it would be a lot of work, and the devil is in details. (Also, writing JavaScript code inside HTML attributes is icky; one would do well to bind event handlers from JavaScript code using `addEventListener`.)

Answer (score 0):

`<a href=someURL>someText</a>` is going to only make the text within the anchor clickable to take you to some URL that you specify

`<button (click)='someFunction()'>` is different in a couple of ways. In your UI it is going to create a clearly clickable button rather than some underlined text. Clicking the button will then perform some sort of function that you specify that button to perform whether thats a JavaScript/TypeScript function or something else.

`<div onClick>` is similar to button onClick in that it will perform some sort of function that you write, but it makes the whole division a clickable area rather than simply a button.