# Wrong ng-click triggered when nested

Tags: angularjs, cross-browser, angularjs-ng-click

I have a problem with nested ng-clicks which is somehow related to: 
[Two nested click events with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15390393/two-nested-click-events-with-angularjs) and [Nested ng-click's in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677011/nested-ng-clicks-in-ie9).

I have the following html structure while the functions use $event.stopPropagation() to not call _outerFunction(). That works fine using the mouse. However, using the keyboard to navigate to either the first  element or the 'hover_Button' and pressing 'Enter' will always call the _outerFunction() and not the actual ng-click of the element.

```
<div class="big_button" ng-click="_outerFunction($event)" title="foo">
    <div class="section">
        <a ng-href="" ng-click="_innerFunction1($event);" title="foo1"></a>
         <div class="hover_Button">
              <a ng-href="" ng-click="_innerFunction2($event);"> <i class="small-button" title="foo2"></i></a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm out of guesses why the enter event is passed to the underlying ng-click and not just used by the element that is active.

Comment: Give us a plunker or fiddle to look at and we can help.

Comment: The HTML presented here is wrong - the `<a title="foo">` is malformed, a closing `</h4>` out of nowhere.

Comment: Sorry, I adjusted the HTML and It should be valid now.

Comment: @m_hau see http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/535/ .  if you click om inner anchor tags it will fire both inner ng-click and outer one.

Comment: @Navaneeth yes, but mouse click is not a problem. Its using the keyboard