# How to map a nested object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have to populate the li element with data stored as a JSON object.
With "title" it works simple. But it's not when talking about name's
values. How can I map the subMenu object to get the name?

```
    <ul>
      {data.map(({ title, subMenu }) => (
                <li className="mobileMenu-body-nav-item">
                    <button className="mobileMenu-body-nav-item-btn"> 
                 *** here I have to put name ***
                    </button>
                </li>
     ))}
    </ul>
```

JSON object

```
[
   {
    "title": "Breeds",
    "subMenu": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Dog Breeds"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Cat Breeds"
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "About Pet Adoption",
    "subMenu": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "About Dog Adoption"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "About Cat Adoption"
        }
      ]
   }
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call `map` again, like this:

```
 <ul>
    {data.map(({ title, subMenu }) => (
        <li className="mobileMenu-body-nav-item">
            <button className="mobileMenu-body-nav-item-btn">
                {subMenu.map(({ name }) => (<span>{name}</span>))}
            </button>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Change the `<span>` tag to match however you want this content to be rendered.

Also, if this is React, don't forget to [set the `key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) appropriately when using `map`:

```
<ul>
    {data.map(({ title, subMenu }) => (
        <li key={title} className="mobileMenu-body-nav-item">
            <button className="mobileMenu-body-nav-item-btn">
                {subMenu.map(({ name }) => (<div key={name}>{name}</div>))}
            </button>
        </li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: So good to see that "Also" at the end. People usually miss pointing that out!

Comment: Also note that [`div`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) is not a valid child of [`button`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element). Perhaps `span`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the link! Super good to know, I learned something useful today.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments on the accepted answer `div` elements are not valid children of `buttons` ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020667/div-not-allowed-as-child-element-of-button)) and while one should assign a `key` to mapped elements in React using the index of the iterated array is not always ideal. (see the [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) or [related article](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) from T.J.Crowder's comment).

Given that you are mapping a nested list it seems more appropriate to structure it as such. Here using the `title` as the outer `li` key (though a more definite unique property would be better) and the `subMenu.id` as a key for the inner `li`.

```
<ul>
  {data.map(({ title, subMenu }) => (
    <li key={title} className='mobileMenu-body-nav-item'>
      <ul>
        {subMenu.map(({ id, name }) => (
          <li key={id}>
            <button className='mobileMenu-body-nav-item-btn'>{name}</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```