# How to create an overlay for a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble creating an overlay style for a Bootstrap button.

I have the following button code:

```
<button id="btnTest" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-certificate"></span>
    &nbsp;
    Test
    <div class="btn-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
    </div>
</button>
```

That's the layout of the button I'd like and I've implemented the following CSS:

```
.btn-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

This make the overlay cover the entire container div (not sure how that's happening) and not just overlaying the entire button.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Once I get the overlay part I'll worry about centering the `fa-refresh` icon.

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885444/why-cant-a-button-element-contain-a-div You can't put a div tag inside a button tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t3ptae1o/

HTML

```
<button id="btnTest" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span class="fa fa-certificate"></span>
    &nbsp;
    Test
    <span class="btn-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>
    </span>
</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
  position: relative;
}
.btn-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

You need to add `position: relative;` to the `.btn` so that the overlay with `absolute` position styles itself relative to the `.btn`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below. I have move the icons to the CSS. I'm not sure when you want the animation to happen, so nothing is in there now.

```css
.button-container {
  position: relative;
}

button:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0a3"
}

button:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f021"
}

button>span {
  margin: 0 0.7em;
}

.btn-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="button-container">
  <button id="btnTest" class="btn btn-primary"><span>Test</span></button>
  <span class="btn-overlay"></span>
</div>
```