# How to write code for firefox click event using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click event is not working on firefox but it's working in chrome. why?

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

$("#id").prev('div').find('button').find('div.classname').click(function(){
alert("Testing");
});


}, 3000);
```

Comment: Why are you binding it after 3 seconds? Why are you not binding the click to the button, but its child? Why is there a block element in your button?

Comment: Check if firefox is returning an element or not ? Type "$("#id").prev('div').find('button').find('div.classname')" in firefox console and see if there any element with that selector.

Comment: The problem must be something else. jQuery and it's click method are stable enough to work properly on all popular browsers.

Comment: You can't have a DIV inside a button, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885444/why-cant-a-button-element-contain-a-div

Comment: @undefined not if you don't follow standards. That's why standards are important. Despite the fact that html is often very forgiving (in most borwsers), when you go outside the standards you can get weird behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind the click event to the button itself, and not the div inside it, that will work :

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

$("#id").prev('div').find('button').click(function(){
alert("Testing");
});


}, 3000);
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aur7dwL4/

However, as noted above by @Barmar, having a div inside of a button is invalid HTML markup.