# Cannot use <div> inside of <button>, but clickable divs are considered bad. What is "correct" approach?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, accessibility

I am building a React App which takes the form of a calendar where the users should be able to click on days on the calendar. These days are represented by large-ish squares, so that they can contain information for that day. For accessibility reasons, using `<button>`s seemed to be the wisest option, but my research ([Why can't a <button> element contain a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15885444/why-cant-a-button-element-contain-a-div)) + (https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-button-element.html#the-button-element) indicates that putting divs inside of buttons is not correct. The only other option I can think of would be to make the days into `<div>`s of their own, but make them clickable and manually give them `tabIndex` and `role` features as appropriate for accessibility purposes.

What is the correct html tag or approach for a clickable area that should also contain possibly multiple `<div>`s inside of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<span>` elements within a `<button>` and it be **valid** HTML.

```html
<button>
  <span>Three Different Spans</span>
  <span>But Perfectly Valid</span>
  <span>HTML!</span>
</button>
```

As you can style a span any way you want this shouldn't cause you any issues.

**However:** if you find that you need a clickable area (that you think should be a button, which certainly sounds correct for a calendar!) is requiring several containers, the odds are that you are designing it incorrectly and may need to reconsider the design.

You could fall back on CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors to add the complexity you require (without seeing the design it is hard to give any solid advice).

If you really aren't sure, you could add an `aria-label` to the `<button>` element and (yet again depending on content) add `aria-hidden="true"` to all internal items.

```html
<button aria-label="function of the button, this will be read to screen readers and other assistive tech">
  <!-- this should be unnecessary, but depending on the content this is a technique to fix any issues caused by the button content -->
  <span aria-hidden="true">Three Different Spans</span>
  <span aria-hidden="true">But Perfectly Valid</span>
  <span aria-hidden="true">HTML!</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the `div` in an anchor:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)"><div>Hello World!</div></a>
```