# HTML5 input versus button

Tags: html

I'm just wondering if input is part of the HTML5 spec or is button the better way or is there something else even better to use.

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>

<button type="submit">submit</button>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use).

Comment: Good link. It's type=submit here, though, so not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

From the [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button):

"`<button>` elements are much easier to style than `<input>` elements. You can add inner HTML content (think `<em>`, `<strong>` or even `<img>`), and make use of :after and :before pseudo-element to achieve complex rendering while `<input>` only accepts a text value attribute."

Answer (score 1):

Their difference lies in how you use them.  Whilst their basic function is the same the main difference is that you can put HTML in a `<button>` element.

`<button>` also is known to have issues in some versions of `IE` (IE6)

Comment: Everything is a problem in IE (IE6) :-)