# Can IE 9 handle form attribute of button tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Does Internet Explorer 9 support the "form" attribute of the button tag? In particular, clicking the button in the following example submits the form in Firefox and Chrome, but does nothing in IE 9:

```
<form id="myform" action="/action" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='foo' value='bar' />
</form>

<!-- Other content here, irrelevant for this example -->

<button form="myform">Click me</button>
```

Comment: The table at the end of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) has a pretty "?" regarding this attribute support on IE...

Comment: But clicking a simple button isn't supposed to submit the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It is not supported in IE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_form.asp).

Unfortunatelty, the support for the button element has never been a priority among browser makers.

**Edit:** this question: [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use) may be relevant, and the accepted answer has a link to a page telling why people avoid the button tag.

Comment: I guess it never will be a priority. Even forms are almost obsolete now with JavaScript.