# Running custom script with the <button> or <input type="button"> tags in html

Tags: html, perl

I have a button which I named "delete" that, when clicked on, runs a perl script.

```
<button type="button">
                <p>delete</p>
```

What should I add to this to allow a custom script to run? I want it to run a perl script ,sorry for being so vague.

Comment: Your question and title are confusing. Your title asks what element to use to run a script, and your question says you already run a script when you click a button. Please clarify.

Comment: You mean a click handler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use

Comment: Do you want to run JavaScript? If yes, learn about event handling: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to run a Perl program in response to a button click in a web browser.

1. Use the ActiveState PerlScript plugin for Internet Explorer and run it client side. I don't think this is supported any more, and it had a highly limited install base when it was supported (making it suitable for Intranets only (and then only barely)).
2. To use Server Side Perl.

I'll assume you mean that latter as it is the only sane way.

First - replace the button with a submit button.

```
<input type="submit" value="Your label">
```

or

```
<button type="submit">Your label</button>
```

The latter lets you include images and other markup in the content.

Second — put it in a `<form>` with the `action` attribute set the to the URL of your Perl program.

Third — Configure your web server to run that program when the URL is hit. How you do that depends on which web server you are using and how you plan to interface it with the script. I generally recommend [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) for a good mix of efficiency and flexibility and then connect it to my webserver with [FastCGI](https://metacpan.org/module/Plack%3a%3aHandler%3a%3aFCGI).

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about adding an onclick handler, you have a few options.

Probably the simplest (but least abstracted) way would just to simply do something like:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">delete</button>
```

To add a click handler programatically, which is typically the more recommended way, you could do something like:

```
<button id="btnDelete">delete</button>

<script>
document.getElementById("btnDelete").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
</script>
```