# Trouble with Javascript Validator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple checkbox and button that will verify that a user has read a TOS.  For some reason, my code doesn't work.  Page loads, but pressing the button doesn't have the desired effect.  Firebug says I'm error free, so I figure I'm misunderstanding how something works.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?  I'm still pretty new to Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
    if(document.getElementById("TOSbox").checked)
    {
       window.location.href = "/give.html";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("TOSWarning").innerHTML="You need to agree to the TOS first.";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    This is where the TOS goes.
    <br>
    <form name="TOSform" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="TOSbox" value="checked">I have read and agree to the Terms of Service.<br>
        <button onclick="validateForm()">I Agree</button> 
    </form>
    <p id="TOSWarning"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Make sure to prevent the default behavior of the form.

Comment: *"I am trying to create a simple checkbox and button that will verify that a user has read a TOS"* That's easy! The answer is: **No, they haven't**. No need to look at the checkbox at all.

Comment: @elclanrs does the code look like OP knows how the prevent the default behaviour?

Comment: @Kay: Maybe not, that's what Google is for, now OP got the search term "prevent default form javascript" and boom thousands of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<button>` needs a [`type="button"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), for starters to avoid submitting the form (or return false when the form isn't valid). Also, you're using `getElementById` but your checkbox has no id, only a name. Try:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="TOSBox" id="TOSbox" value="checked">I have read and agree to the Terms of Service.<br>
<button type="button" onclick="validateForm();">I Agree</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return `false` to prevent the default submission behavior.

```
<button onclick="validateForm(); return false;">I Agree</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079197/1026459

When a button is used without a type inside of a form, its default type is submit.

Consider using `<button type="button"...>` to avoid posting the form when the button is pressed.

Also, in the javascript you are using, you are looking for an `id="TOSbox"`, but your checkbox is actually only using `name="TOSbox"`. You should probably add the id to it

```
<input type="checkbox" id="TOSbox" name="TOSbox" value="checked">
```