# Rules and advantages of using input_tag, a_tag, div_tag and button_tag as button in HTML

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, button

What are the rules of using a_tag, div_tag and button_tag as button in HTML?

I am a Ruby on Rails user. Rails default gives input_tag and button_tag as button. What are the advantages of using other tags beside button_tag itself? When should I use each one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without introducing any attributes, there is one HTML button element:

```html
<button></button>
```

There is also a generic form input element which can be set to render as a button:

```html
<input />
```

Both of these elements accept three button-type attributes which let user agents determine their behaviour (as buttons):

```html
<button type="button">Regular button</button>
<input type="button" value="Regular button" />

<button type="submit">Form submit button</button>
<input type="submit" value="Form submit button" />

<button type="reset">Form reset button</button>
<input type="reset" value="Form reset button" />
```

These two elements behave identically when these attributes are set. The main difference between the two elements is that the `button` element can contain HTML whereas an `input` element may only contain text passed in through its `value` attribute (see [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use?rq=1)):

```html
<button type="button">
    <span>This is perfectly valid</span>
</button>

<input type="button" value="No HTML permitted here" />
```

(As a side note, a `button` element accepts any [*phrasing content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) descendant which *isn't* interactive content (another button or a checkbox, for example).

*However*, from an accessibility perspective any HTML element which accepts a `role` attribute can be turned into a button simply by declaring `role="button"`:

```
<a role="button"></a>
<div role="button"></div>
<span role="button"></span>
...
```

These are all perfectly valid, and complying user agents will treat all of these as buttons.

How you use them depends entirely on the context. If your button is within a form, you're going to want to use an `input` element; if your button is standalone on your page, you're going to want to use a `button` element; if your button is found within a list of hyperlinks, you may as well just use an `a` element with a `role` of "button", but you could just use `button` here as well if you wanted to. Bear in mind that the `type` attribute's `submit`, `reset` and `button` values are only valid on `button` and `input` elements and will have no effect when added to any other element with a "button" `role`.

Comment: Thanks. But I still don't understand why it is designed that way. Having all these methods to do the same thing seems very redundant to me. Is there benefits to use `a` among `a` list? If `button` supports everything better and more natively, why do we not just stick with `button`? Is it because `button` is harder to stylize?