# populating an HTML table with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, post, json.net

an HTML table requires 2 cells of data from a JSON object that a default.aspx.cs file receives via POST.  The task of parsing this JSON object is a little tricky as the data can vary in contents quite considerably. However, VS' immediate window confirms that the JsonResult[""] nomenclature is working fine (IOW, I am succesfully receiving data from a JSON object in a POST request). However, I get inconsistent performance when trying to implement the code below.

```
  if (Request.HttpMethod.ToString() == "POST") {

    if (Request.Form["Item"] != null) {
      Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject JsonResult = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Request.Form["Item"]);

      if (JsonResult["requestType"] != null) {
        cartItem = new CartItem(
          "TestCode",
          JsonResult["containerType"].ToString(),
          JsonResult["resultType"].ToString(),
          1,
          3.99
          );

        // populate empty cells with data, place cells in row and place row in table.
        foreach (var item in cartItem.getCartCells().Select((value, index) => new { value, index })) {
          try {
            cartCells.Add(new TableCell());
            int i = cartCells.Count() - 1;
            cartCells[i].Text = (item.value != null || item.value != "") ? item.value : " - ";
            tr.Cells.Add(cartCells[i]);
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Write("shopping cart failed to run: " + ex.Message);
            break;
          }
        }
        shoppingCart.Rows.Add(tr);
      }
    }
  }
```

Previously, I had a stub performing a similar task without any problems.  Now however, the additional row that this code is supposed to add to my table is not appearing on POST.  Strangely, when I add `Response.Write("Write a test")` after checking the request method, the table builds just fine.  Is there some kind of Async problem going on here? Intellisense and the debugger aren't picking up anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic above is actually sound.  The reason it wasn't working had to do with my submission. I was abstracting data from my form and submitting it with JS (as I actually need rather a lot more data than the form alone encompasses).  What hadn't occured to me was that the button i was using was also submitting my form.  The result was a messy header that, it appears, had been mashed together out of two requests.  The solution was to replace `<button onclick="Service.refresh()"></button>` with `<input type="button" onClick="Service.refresh()">`...

as an aside, this thread may also be useful to people suffering similar headaches: [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)