# jsp two buttons in a form and javascript form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

I am working on a web project using structs2. I have a form with submit button and another button. I am using javascript functions for form validation. My problem is that when I click the other button the form validation function works.
my jsp:

```
<h2>New Form</h2>
<s:form  action="aa.action" name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return(validateForm())">
<s:textfield name="formnumber" size="20" />
.
.
<button value="add" name="add">Add</button>
.
.
<s:submit method="create" key="xxx" value="xxx"  />
```

When i click anyone of the the button the validation function will excecute.I dont want excecute the validation function on *add* button click.

Comment: just call the function on ur submit button

Comment: Should the add button submit the form? It is not apparent from your question if that is the case or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default button always submit the form so add `type="button"` it will stop

```
<button type="button" value="add" name="add">Add</button>
```

OR Use

```
<input type="button" name="add" value="Add" />
```

Comment: Another solution is to use `<input type="button" />`, [that gives less problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/469084/1654265).

Comment: @AndreaLigios i know but OP code use button thats why i am not mentioning that,thanks for your update `:-)`

Comment: Feel free to add it to your answer as a second option. The fact that OP is not mentioning it may be because he doesn't know that, instead of being a requirement to use a button ;)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `onclick`. You don't need it here. The `type="add"` already submits the form. Your concrete problem is likely caused because the `onclick` of the `<form>` has returned false.

```
<input type="button" name="method" value="Add" class="button"
    onclick="location.href='Employeelist.jsp'" />
```

Comment: Where do you see `onclick` in OP?

Answer (score 0):

You should mention type="button".
Otherwise **it will submit the current URL again**.

```
<button type="button" value="Add" name="add"/>
```

details about "type" in html 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Java Script Form validation can be 
 
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp) 
[Tutorials point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_form_validations.htm)
[javaScript Coder](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.html)

if you familier with java script libraries you can use [validate.js](http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/)

Answer (score -1):

type : What type of widget you want.
vlaue : The text what you want in that.
name : The id of that purticulat widget.