# :before :after not working on the input type submit?

Tags: html, css

why the :before and :after not working on the `input type='submit'`

here is my code

```
input.submit:before {     
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font: normal 18px/1 'Genericons';
    content: '\f400';
}
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML as well.. maybe make a Fiddle to show.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's because `:before` and `:after` only works for nodes that can have child nodes. In your case, using a button would work since it can take HTML.

---

> [5.12.3 The :before and :after pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/selector.html#before-and-after)
>
> The ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used to insert generated content before or after an element's content.

Since input cannot have content, it does not support it

Comment: Explains a lot. I haven't found this answer somewhere else though.

Comment: @Juan Mendes I find your answer more helpful than the original "duplicate". Thanks for clearifying!

Comment: @webprogrammer Especially when that answer is catered to IE7 and suggests using jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

Use a `<button>`

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/c93PW/)

HTML

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

CSS

```
button:before {    
display: inline-block;
    height: 20px; 
    background: #F00;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
     font: normal 18px/1 'Genericons';
    content: '\f400';
}
```

Comment: This does not allow to submit the form, it is an HTML element but it is not an input.

Comment: @iLen - not sure what you mean. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/469077/2930477

Comment: @iLen `The type of the button. Possible values are:
submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.` [MDN button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Answer (score -8):

try this, in ur code u r targetting button with class `submit`, but u should target button with type `submit` like below

```
 input[type="submit"]:before {
         display: inline-block;
         -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
         font: normal 18px/1 'Genericons';
         content: '\f400'; 
    }
```