# submit form: button or input?

Tags: html, css, forms

what is the best approach? Should I use this:

```
<button type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="submit">ENVOYER&nbsp;</button>
```

or this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="submit">
```

And why?

Many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disadvantage of  is that it's not fully supported by older browsers. `IE6/7,` for example, don't display it correctly.

Unless you have some specific reason, it's probably best to stick to `<input type='submit' />.`

`<input type='submit' />` doesn't support HTML inside of it, since it's a single self-closing tag.