# My form always submits when the button is clicked, no matter what I do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a relatively simple form. I am using jQuery to select the submit button, and as of right now, I'm just trying to display an alert when clicked.

The Problem: The button is using it's default action, no matter what I do. So basically, no alert displays, and I'm stuck with the submitted parameters which are appended to the end of the url in my address bar.

I have tried using `e.preventDefault();`, `e.preventDefault(true);`, `e.stopImmediatePropogation()`, and `e.stopImmediatePropogation(true);`.

I've even tried putting those in a `document.ready()` block.

The registration form is in a modal panel, though I don't think that should matter... (Should it?)

I guess now I'll show you the code. I really don't understand why it's not working. I'd appreciate any help:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/bHCC58w4 (full document)

```
    <form id="registerForm">
        <a class="close"></a>
        <h3>Register Today! - It's FREE!</h3>
        <p>Registering only takes seconds, and puts you into direct contact with a designer. On top of all that, you can add documents, images, and other files to your project dashboard. What are you waiting for? It's free!</p>
        <img src="images/formfish.png" alt="Goldy the goldfish helps users register. It looks like he stepped out for a minute. Sorry about that!" />
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your full name." title="We just need your first and last name." class="masterTooltip" />
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email." title="We won't send you spam. Pinky swear." class="masterTooltip"  />
        <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Your username." title="Your username must be unique." class="masterTooltip" />
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password." title="Make your password hard to guess." class="masterTooltip" />
        <button id="register">Sign up</button>
    </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT: http://pastebin.com/bD2fYPsh (full document)

```
        $("#register").on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Hello!");
        });
```

Here is a semi-live version of the site. It's got no working functionality other than the jQuery animations. I don't know if it will help you guys or not: http://graphicgoldfish.com/creativecodefish/

Comment: your code seems right, on signup click it is posting

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wJ6r8/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/35LWJ/

Comment: working fine http://jsfiddle.net/Hq3uZ/

Comment: It really isn't, and if you isolate it, that's not changing the fact that when you put it back onto the html, it's still broken.

Comment: If you wanna prevent default action on form submit then use `$('#registerForm').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: Related: [There are 3 supported types for a button, the default type is submit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10079197/1026459)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the button so it's just a button, not a submit button:

```
<button id="register" type="button">Sign up</button>
```

By default, buttons are of the type submit which will cause the form itself to submit.

Comment: That makes sense, and the form is no longer submitting, but it's still not displaying the alert for some reason.

Comment: There must be something interfering with your code.  Is the actual form present on the page you linked to?  This one: http://graphicgoldfish.com/creativecodefish/

Comment: Yeah, if you click the "Start Today" button.

Comment: Hmm, the markup for that Sign up button is this: <button id="regSubmit">Sign up</button> and I cannot see any event handlers being hooked up to this button in your javascript files.  Something is clearly missing, right?

Comment: The live site has no functionality. I linked pastebin files in the original markup. I will upload the files now to the ftp.

Comment: It's been uploaded, so you should be able to see the javascript.

Comment: Just saw it :-)  Move the code which applies the handler to the register button outside of the signup button click .... you cannot call $(document).ready(...) inside a click event.  It will not work. See an updated pastebin here: http://pastebin.com/VRDt6rCM where I've moved the code around at the bottom.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing. And I'm a dunce. Send me a message for some cookies. <3

Answer (score -1):

There are a bit different event handlers. I think you are better off using plain javascript for this:

```
document.getElementById("register").addEventHandler("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // etc
}
```

Comment: There are different ways of stopping the propagation depending on how you specify the event handler. (Maybe the guy who downvoted my answer can point you to the differences. I can, but will not do it now. ;-) )