# Font Awesome - Change color - "&#xf0c7" format

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I know it's easy to change the color if you use the standard format and css :

```
<i class="icon-cog"></i>
```

But I'm forced to use the html format (&#xf0c7) of the icon:

```
<input id="btn-save-workout" type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-sm" value="&#xf0c7; Save">
```

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

Not sure it's possible with this syntax. I tried putting a div around with a color without success.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button id="btn-save-workout" type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-sm">&#xf0c7; Save</button>
```

Functionally, `<button type="submit">Submit</button>` is identical to what you are doing.

Then change the `color` on that button.

Here's [some information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059) on `button` vs `input`.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly with a button! 
    <button id="btn-save-workout" type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg color-save "></i> Save</button>
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m94kij6kxq8f2ga/iconColors.png?dl=0

Comment: Thanks I just did! This code is now live in my software if you want to check it out :) 
https://maximumtrainer.com/news