# `this` not scoped in React Component event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying out the new React v0.13 ES6 component classes and I've run into a problem. When I try to have a click handler within the class call a function the component has received through props it throws an error saying that `this` isn't defined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyComp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='button' value='Fetch Data' onClick={this.handleClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleClick(evt) {
    // ...do stuff

    this.props.fetch(); // throws error: `cannot read property 'this' of undefined`
  }
}
```

I double-checked and I can access the props from within the `render` function so I know that they exist in the place that they should.

When I use the old `React.createClass` syntax the same code works fine so I'm wondering if I missed something. I know I can fix this easily by just binding `this` to the `handleClick` method in the render function but I'd rather not if it's something simple.

Comment: *"I'm wondering if I missed something"* http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
<input type='button' value='Fetch Data' onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

Into this:

```
<input type='button' value='Fetch Data' onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```

Or add a `constructor` with the following:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

Or if you're using ES7 features you could look into either creating your own or [using an existing](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator) autobind decorator.

On a somewhat related note: consider using the [`button`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469077/517528) element instead.

Comment: `constructor() {  
 super();  
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);  
}`