# Javascript why onClick getting called by enter-key

Tags: javascript, onclick, key, enter

I've got a button with the onClick-event and a textfield with onKeyDown-event.

```
Button: onclick="myFunc(3)"
Textfield: onKeyDown="if(event.keyCode==13) myFunc(3);"
```

Somehow the button is getting called if I press the enter-key and I don't know why.

Comment: We'd need a **lot** more information to work with to be able to usefully answer this question.

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML. In particular, is the button a submit button? Also, how do you know a button click is being triggered, since you are calling the same function in both cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you press Enter in a text field, you trigger a form submission and browsers simulate clicking on the first submit button of the form.

You can avoid this by preventing the default action of the keypress (not keydown) event.

```js
var s = document.querySelector('[type=submit]');
var t = document.querySelector('[type=text]');
var f = document.querySelector('form');

t.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("enter pressed")
  }
});

t.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="/">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That was my *other* theory, but given that the question lacked any information about a form or that the button was a submit...

Answer (score 0):

You will come across this situation if you have a `<button>` element inside your form(if the purpose of the button is to not to submit the form) without specifying the type as `type="button"`. Please refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079197) for more information.