# CSS button animation doesn't work, can't figure out why

Tags: html, css

I have a https://jsfiddle.net/wmrq3ora/ with an example that is not working and I don't know how to fix it.

```
<div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="OVDJE" class="button-blue hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" onclick="upisnik();"/>
</div>
```

and the styles:

```
 .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  background: #3498db;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50%;
  transform-origin: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active {
  color: #3498db;
}
.hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:hover:before, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:focus:before, .hvr-shutter-out-horizontal:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.button-blue{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display:block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 35px;
    border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: #3498db;
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;
    padding-top:8px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    font-weight:700;
}

.submit{
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    height:35px;
}
```

I am trying to get it to work like http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/  background, shutter out transition. Only with a bit different colors. But cant get it to work. 
What am i missing? Are some styles i used the problem here?
Ignore the function call..

Comment: Are you using the Hover.css library? Or are you just copying the relevant CSS out of it?

Comment: change the `<input>` to an `<a>`.  That's what the hvr-shutter-out-horizontal was designed for.

Comment: I copied out a portion of it from there, yes.

Comment: @andi I thought that it could be used anywhere, regardless of tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that `:before` pseudo-element doesn't work on `input` elements. You change the `input` field to `button` instead.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/987447) regarding the pseudo-element.

```
<div class="submit">
  <button type="submit" class="button-blue hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" onclick="upisnik();">OVDJE</button>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmrq3ora/2/)

Comment: Ok, thanks, ill try it out and get back to you. And can you explain why? Is there such a big difference between input, a and button tag?

Comment: @IvanHorvatin :before and :after pseudo-elements only work on container elements because of the way they are rendered as a child of that element. `<input>text</input>` is invalid, but `<button>text</button>` is valid.

Comment: @IvanHorvatin Great! Glad it helped.

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan can i ask you about the thing Max Sassen said. Does a button tag work the same way as input? Capable of sending a form when pressed?

Comment: @IvanHorvatin Yes, if you set the `type` attribute as `submit`. E.g. `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`. Check this [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.submit.html).

Comment: Thanks @RobinCarloCatacutan Means a lot to me. Ok, one more question and i will be out of your hair :)
If i want to add an animation like when i click the button acts like it is clicked, do i need to make the animation and apply it when on click happens like the one i have inside already?

Comment: @IvanHorvatin Yeah, I believe you have to apply it when on click happens, if you do mean animation. But if you mean like the one you already have(having outline or border when clicked), you can make use css `:active and :focus`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hseahp63/)

Comment: @RobinCarloCatacutan Thanks a lot, forgot about that for a moment there. Really gratefull for your help! You helped me a bunch!

Comment: @IvanHorvatin Cool no prob, I'm glad I have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo elements can only be defined on container elements. Because of the way they are rendered within the container itself as a DOM element. inputs cannot contain other elements hence they're not supported. A button on the other hand, although a form element, supports them because it's a container of other sub elements.

more info on: [12.1 The :before and :after pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content)

```
<button type="submit" class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" onclick="upisnik();">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wmrq3ora/4/

Comment: So..are you saying instead of input in a form tag i could use button instead and it will work the same way as input?

Comment: Im asking this because i have a ajaxform running in the background when a submitHandler occurs. So this would be a good info for me.

Comment: Yes it will work on the same way as an input. 
There was a difference before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use#answer-469084
but its was only concidering to older versions of IE (IE6)

Comment: Thanks for that piece of info :)

Comment: np, glad I could help you