# Blue Button HTML CSS Change size

Tags: html, css

How can i code a blue Button with the length of 50 and witdh of 50 in Html ?

I'm really new at it

i allready have a button but i dont  know how to change the color and the size of it

```
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to style elements, and they all use CSS. The most common one is including a CSS file with all the desired styles, but for the sake of this example, you can include a style tag in your HTML.

```
<style>
  button {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

Note, that I've also made the display type of the element `block` to give me the ability to manipulate it's width AND height.

Comment: `background-color: blue;` to be more close to the OP question. Anyway, nice answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" style="background-color:blue;width:1330px;" value="click Me">
```

Comment: `<button>` tag is not the same as `<input type="button">`. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use

Answer (score 2):

Well to summarize things for you, there are 3 possibilities that you can follow:

**1. Use an inline style for your button:**

---

```
<button type="button" style="display: block; width: 50px;height: 50px; background-color:blue;">Click Me!</button>
```

**2. Use the `<style>` tag to style your button:**

---

```
<style>
   button {
     display: block;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color:blue;
   }
</style>
```

**3. Put your style in an external CSS File and include it in the
    `<head>` of your HTML.**

---

```
<link href="path/to/your/file.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Note:**

The choice of which approach to use, depends on the situation, for your simple case you can go with the inline styling.

**This is a simple snippet:**

```html
<button type="button" style="display: block; width: 50px;height: 50px; background-color:blue;">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very quick solution would be to add the styles inline like this:

```
<button type="button" style="display: block; width: 50px; height: 50px;">Click Me!</button>
```