# Javascript will not pass information into function from html

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so very new to Javascript. Trying to learn the code by simply changing the text on a button using an external javascript file. But I can't even get javascript to read the buttons valueexternally, in Chrome's debug tools I see my button value is btn="". It reads the button object but can't read its properties.

```
<html>
<head>

    <title> Test  </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Gle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div><canvas id="Gle" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
    <div>
        <h2>Enter the mass and coordinates</h2> 
        <input id="txtbox" type="text" /><br/>
        <button id="btn" onclick="change()">Add</button>

    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

The Gle.js

```
"use strict";


function change() {
    var x = document.getElementById("btn").value;
    var elem = document.getElementById("btn");
    var txt = document.getElementById("txtbox");
    txt.text = elem.value;
    elem.value = "Ok";
    }
```

When I debug the **x** value it is "", nothing changes on my screen. I am using brackets IDE.

Comment: Why not just use the `this` keyword to get the button?

Comment: 1. Please create a MCVE. This is **not** how you post a proper question on SO. 2. What "value" do you expect the button to have?

Comment: I'm expecting to have the button title "Add" appear from x in the debug watch window.

Comment: The "id" element has no value.  `value` is an attribute.  You set it with `<tag value="xxx">`.  The "id" element does however have child content.  You can access that through the `innerHTML` property.  i.e.  `document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x` is empty because `'#btn'` doesn't have the 'value' attribute specified. The "Add" string is inside its inner HTML (or text),

```
alert(document.getElementById("btn").innerText);
```

And you can index `this` in the event scope, it's a reference of `'#btn'`, `this.innerText`.

A alternative is to get the `'#btn'` child nodes values, which is cross-browser.

```
alert(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

This alert the first text specified in the element inner.

Comment: Thanks Guys, this helpful to connect the dots, sometimes one just has to put there thoughts out there.  I've noticed that the <button> object behaves weaker than the <input type="button"> object, as in less easy to manipulate.

Comment: @CromeX If you're looking for differences you can check http://stackoverflow.com/q/469059#26818133, this answer has a good quote

Answer (score 1):

> I'm expecting to have the button title "Add" appear?

The button doesn't have a `value` attribute so its `value` property is an empty string.

"Add" is the content of the text node inside the button element.

```
var x = document.getElementById("btn").firstChild.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by assigning `value` attribute to your `button`

```
<button id="btn" onclick="change()" value="Add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the text of a button based on what's in the input box the code could look like this:

```
<button id="myButton">Change Me</button>
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="To This"/>
```

and in the JS:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").click(function(){
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value
    document.getElementById("myButton").innerText = inputValue
    // You could also use 'this' to refer to document.getElementById("myButton"):
    // this.innerText = inputValue
})
```