# In todays modern browsers, is there ever any advantage to using input[type="button"] over <button>?

Tags: html, button, forms

From all I know about `<button>`s vs. `input[type="button"]`, I can't see any advantages that would compel me to use `input[type="button"]` - are there any?

Note that I don't care about < IE11.

Comment: Your question title and text don't match -- are you comparing `<button>` to `<input type="submit">` or `<input type="button">`? Or both?

Comment: Thanks for catching that - updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I saw that, but that was ancient (from 2009!), and there were few recent answers or comments. Plus, if I had posted a comment there, I doubt it would've gotten any traction, and certainly not as immediately as I did by creating a new question...perhaps a scenario stackoverflow needs to address?

Comment: Nothing has changed, fundamentally, to the definition of those elements since 2009, so why would the answers change (besides trivial things like caveats about certain old browser versions).

Comment: I suppose...but the caveats about certain old browser versions were most of the reasons I was hearing for input[type="submit"] vs. button.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there are any more technical reasons, but my preference has been for simpler HTML and CSS.

It is easier to write `<button>Button</button>` and style it with `button {…}` than it is for `<input type="button" value="Button'>` and `input[type="button"] {…}`. Not to mention your `<input type="button">` possibly inheriting unfortunate `input {…}` styles, requiring more lines of CSS to undo the damage.

Both methods have been working for ages (IE6+?), though I believe some older browsers had `<button>` clicks submit forms by default unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good question because the answer is not what you might expect.

It turns out the most pertinent consideration is not the `<input>`/`<button>` element at all... but the `type` attribute.

Here's why:

The default behaviour of `<button>` is identical to `<input type="submit" />`

If you want to get a `<button>` to behave (as well as look) like `<input type="button" />`, you'll need to use...

```
<button type="button">
```