# <input class="btn btn-default btn-sm users-btn"> issue with underlined text

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

As is written in the question [<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use) I use:

```
"<input class.."
```

insted of:

```
"<button.."
```

I do it because I do not send anything through the button. Issue is I got underlined text like:

[image]

How to "delete" a red line?

Comment: Your browser or editor does not recognize the word. It's not a CSS or HTML thing, It just doesn't recognize it, just like the spellcheck in Microsoft Word and stuff.

Comment: can you update your question with full html tag for button both for `input` & `button` tag

Comment: Set `spellcheck='false'` to your input.

Comment: why you need to add this attribute when spelling is already right..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the spellcheck error,  you can turn it off by adding '`spellcheck="false"`' to your input, i.e:

```
"<input class='blah' spellcheck='false'.. >"
```

Comment: why you need to add this attribute when spelling is already right..??

Comment: @swapnilnax I do not know, but the is the answer! Thanks Shtut, in 8 minutes you will get +1 ;-)