# Javascript: Unable to log text input to console

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to log a text input to the developer console in Chrome.
Here is my html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <form name="myForm">
      <label name='header'> Some label </label>
        <input id='userInput' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder="some javascript value comes here" name='myInput'>
<button onclick="someFunction()"> Submit </button>
      </form>
      </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's the JavaScript:

```
<script>
function someFunction(){
var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput');
console.log('userInput);
}
</script>
```

can anybody tell me where am i getting wrong.

Comment: console.log(userInput);  you are adding '

Comment: Syntax error ...

Comment: and then invoke the someFunction like this                                                            someFunction();

Comment: You probably want to log just the input. If so, use `console.log(userInput.value)`. And since your button is inside form it forces page refresh on click. To prevent it, add type for your button: `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

For the console.log(). You are adding '. It should be console.log(variable_name). In this case console.log(userInput)

```
<input id='userInput' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder="some javascript value comes here" name='myInput'>
<button onclick="someFunction()"> Submit </button>

<script>
function someFunction(){
var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput').value;
console.log(userInput);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your javascript
You wrote `'userInput` but it should be `userInput`

```
<script>
function someFunction(){
var userInput=document.getElementById('userInput');
// WRONG VARIABLE NAME USED console.log('userInput);
console.log(userInput); //RIGHT VARIABLE NAME USED
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A. What you need to log is not the `<input>` textbox (`userInput`), it's the **[value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11563667/2813224)** inside the textbox      (`userInput.value`).

- **Solution:** `console.log(userInput.value)`

B. The requirements for form controls (e.g. `<input>`, `<button>`, etc.) are 
different inside and      outside of a `<form>`.

- **Solution:** add to `<button>` tag: `type="button"` ***or*** move `<button>` tag *outside* of `<form>` tag.

  1. A `<button>` tag needs a [**`type`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079197/2813224) attribute when it's a child of a `<form>`.

     - `<button type='button"` *or* `"submit"` *or* `"reset">`
  2. If a `<button>` tag doesn't have a `type` attribute, then it is a `type="submit"` by default. A submit button will send data of form controls (form tags with `name` attribute) and refresh the page.
  3. A `<button>` *outside* the `<form>` tag doesn't require a `type` attribute.
  4. Any `<input>` needs a `type` or it defaults to `type="text"`
  5. A `type="submit"` *or* `"reset"` *outside* a `<form>` tag needs a `form="`**ID of form**`"`

In the demo, the buttons with black text are `<input>` tags and the buttons with red text are `<button>` tags. Data in a `<form>` ends up either to a server and results can be seen in a response or gets processed in client and can be seen in a log or displayed in DOM. The `<form>` is setup to send data to a live test server to show a response.

### Demo

```js
function xFunction(e) {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
  console.log(userInput.value);
}
```

```css
button {
  color: red
}

form {
  border: 1px solid #000
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <form id="xForm" action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='post'>
        <label> Some label </label>
        <input id='userInput' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder="some javascript value comes here" name='userInput'>
        <button onclick="xFunction()">OP button No type</button>
        <br>
        <label>&lt;input&gt;</label>
        <input type='submit'>
        <input type='reset'><br>
        <label style='color:blue'>This is runs function and doesn't send data: </label>
        <input type='button' value="Button" onclick='xFunction()'><br>
        <label style='color:red'>&lt;button&gt;</label>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        <button type='reset'>Reset</button><br>
        <label style='color:blue'>This is runs function and doesn't send data: </label>
        <button onclick="xFunction()" type='button'> Button</button>
      </form>
      <label>type="submit" outside of form#xForm</label>
      <input type='submit' value='No form attribute'>
      <input type='submit' form='xForm' value='form="ID of <form>"'><br>
      <label style='color:blue'>This is runs function and doesn't send data: </label>
      <button onclick="xFunction()">OP button No type</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```