# Prevent onclick event on a button from firing when hitting Enter in a different box

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, userscripts

I need to have a user input field in the `#wmd-button-bar` of the SE editor, along with a button. The user can enter some data in the input field, and then press a button to process that data. I am using a userscript to achieve this. I have created a separate MVCE of that, and here is its [direct install link](https://gist.github.com/GaurangTandon/b85db9c85d6499df69b584357ab3dabb/raw/419949be384f5cf8330c0137c8369a65a846bece/Demobug.user.js) for Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey.

To reproduce the issue, install the userscript. Reload this page and then click "Edit". You'll notice a new blank input box with a button. Focus the the "Edit summary" box blank, leave it blank, and hit Enter. Instead of submitting the answer box, your caret will now instead focus on the new blank input box.

The same happens if you press Enter inside the "Question title" box.

From the `console.log` messages, you'll notice that there has been instead a `MouseClick` event on the button! This is not expected behavior. In fact, how is this even possible? We just pressed Enter inside the Edit summary box, and didn't even touch either the new blank input or its button. How did it then register a mouse click?

How to fix this?

**Note:** The `e.preventDefault();` inside the button `onclick` handler is necessary. Otherwise, when the user presses the button to process their input data, the answer box submits itself instead.

---

[The Userscript Code](https://gist.github.com/GaurangTandon/b85db9c85d6499df69b584357ab3dabb):

```
function createModal(buttonBar){
    var div = document.createElement("div"),
        input = document.createElement("input"),
        btn = document.createElement("button");

    div.id = "box";

    input.type = "text";

    btn.innerHTML = "Button";
    btn.onclick = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("I was called");
        input.focus();
        console.dir(e);
        console.trace();
    };

    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(btn);

    return div;
}

setInterval(function () {
    var cont = document.querySelector(".wmd-container:not(.processed)"), ul, buttonBar, div;

    if (cont && (ul = cont.querySelector(".wmd-button-bar ul"))) {
        cont.classList.add("processed");

        buttonBar = cont.querySelector("div[id^=wmd-button-bar]");

        div = createModal(buttonBar);
        buttonBar.appendChild(div);
    }
}, 500)
```

Comment: Have you tried defining a keypress event for pressing the enter key and putting e.preventDefault() in the callback? This might help.

Comment: @MarziehBahri Sorry, but, I don't wish to disable the default behavior of pressing the Enter key in the Edit summary box to submit the post. So, I cannot do that.

Comment: One possibility can be - `form` containing only `input` text gets submitted on Enter press. And this is triggering all submit activities like click maybe. If this is the case then you can either remove parent form element or have one more hidden input element. Or add `stopPropagation` to trigger only one submit event through enter press.

Comment: One patchwork you can try is add an event handler for enter press on the input box like -

    function preventSubmission(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

Or set a semaphore/flag in enter handler and check it inside click handler and prevent action accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its default HTML behaviour. All the `buttons` inside a `form` are of `type="submit"`. On pressing `enter`, the most recent button of the `form` is clicked and their handlers are called, by default. To fix this, the buttons are created with `type="button"`.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#a").type)
console.log(document.querySelector("#b").type)
console.log(document.querySelector("#c").type)
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <button id="a" onclick="console.log('a')">Submit type</button>
    <button id="b" onclick="console.log('b')" type="button">Button type</button>
    <input id="c" type="submit" value="Input Submit type">
</form>
```

You can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use) to understand the behaviour of `<button>` and `<input type="button">`.

If you just check in console like, `document.querySelector("#box").children[1].type` it will show as `submit`.

Button, by default, acts as `submit` type unless it is specified explicitly (either `submit`(default)/`reset`/`button`). Just run `document.querySelector("#box").children[1].type=button`. You find it working as expected.

The behaviour is same in cross-browser and tested in `Firefox Nightly` (developer version), `Chrome` and `Safari` and [works a little bit different in `IE`](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/button-tag-in-IE).

Also you can see the click is by default by seeing `console.log(event.detail)` is `0` as it is triggered internally. When triggered with a left click, it would be `1`. [MDN Docs on click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

Answer (score 3):

The short and simple answer, is to force type for your button element:

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

It defaults to `type="submit"`, and that's why it acts accordingly.

Comment: This answer is underrated.

Answer (score 1):

i tried the following code in firefox browser and it works as expected.

```
function createModal(buttonBar){
    var div = document.createElement("div"),
        input = document.createElement("input"),
        btn = document.createElement("button");

    div.id = "box";

    input.type = "text";
    btn.type = "button";

    btn.innerHTML = "Button";
    btn.onclick = function(e){
        console.log("I was called");
        input.focus();
        console.dir(e);
        console.trace();
    };

    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(btn);

    return div;
}

setInterval(function () {
    var cont = document.querySelector(".wmd-container:not(.processed)"), ul, buttonBar, div;

    if (cont && (ul = cont.querySelector(".wmd-button-bar ul"))) {
        cont.classList.add("processed");

        buttonBar = cont.querySelector("div[id^=wmd-button-bar]");

        div = createModal(buttonBar);
        buttonBar.appendChild(div);
    }
}, 500);
```

notice that i have set the `btn.type="button";` this makes sure the form is not submitted and also removed `e.preventDefault();` as button will never submit the form now.

keep in mind that by default if you don't give a `type` to a `button` element then it will behave like a `submit` button.

also the `MouseClick` event was firing because the click event is triggered on submit buttons present within the form when submitting the form. as you had the button without the `type` attribute it was working like a submit button. so the `MouseClick` event was fired when you hit enter (as its submitting the form).

you can verify this by adding an `onclick` handler from your browser developer tool to the `Save edits` submit button and hit enter on the text field.