# i cannot create an element below textbox if password is incorrect

Tags: javascript, html

There is a problem with the following code: I tried to create an element in javascript but the element appears and disappears each time a  click is performed.

```js
function hi() {
  let user = document.getElementById('username').value;
  let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  let cpassword = document.getElementById('cspassword').value;

  if (user == "" || email == "" || password == "" || cpassword == "") {
    alert('no field can be left empty')
  } else if (password != cpassword) {
    let par = document.createElement('p');
    let text = document.createTextNode('passwords do not match');
    par.appendChild(text);
    document.querySelector('form').appendChild(par);
  } else {
    alert('welcome');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>forms</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="myform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="cpassword" id="cspassword" name="cpassword">
    <button onclick="hi();">submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src="forms.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The expected behavior should be the creation of a paragraph if the password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function hi(event) {
  let user = document.getElementById('username').value;
  let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
  let cpassword = document.getElementById('cspassword').value;

  if (user == "" || email == "" || password == "" || cpassword == "") {
    alert('no field can be left empty')
  } else if (password != cpassword) {
    let par = document.createElement('p');
    let text = document.createTextNode('passwords do not match');
    par.appendChild(text);
    document.querySelector('form').appendChild(par);


    event.preventDefault();   // This will prevent page get refresh...

  } else {
    alert('welcome');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>forms</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="myform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="cpassword" id="cspassword" name="cpassword">
    <button onclick="hi(event);">submit</button>
  </form>
  <script src="forms.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `button` tag use `<input type="button" onclick="hi();" value="submit"/>`

see [Button vs input type button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079197/4354201)

```js
function hi(){
let user = document.getElementById('username').value;
let email = document.getElementById('email').value;
let password = document.getElementById('password').value;
let cpassword = document.getElementById('cspassword').value;

if(user == "" || email == "" || password == "" || cpassword == "" ){
  alert('no field can be left empty')
}
else if(password != cpassword){
  let par = document.createElement('p');
  let text = document.createTextNode('passwords do not match');
  par.appendChild(text);
  document.querySelector('form').appendChild(par);
}
else {
  alert('welcome');
}
}
```

```html
<form class="myform">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
            <input type="password" placeholder="cpassword" id="cspassword" name="cpassword">
            <input type="button" onclick="hi();" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: it worked thanks i will keep that in mind and like to learn other things from you

Answer (score 0):

- There is no reason to prefer `<input type="button">` to `<button>` but in your case you should use `<input type="submit">` as your button is supposed to submit a form.
- Maybe you want to check if the message has been posted before creating it again on click.
- You should use [eventlistener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- You can use [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#required) attribute to check for input fields being empty.

**HTML**

```
<form class="myform">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="username" name="">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" placeholder="password" id="password" name="password">
    <input type="password" placeholder="cpassword" id="cspassword" name="cpassword">
    <input id="abc" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
const passwordMatch = (a, b) => a == b;
const fieldsEmpty = (a, b, c, d) => a == "" || b == "" || c == "" || d == "";
var msgPasswordDoesNotMatchDisplayed = false;
var msgPasswordDoesNotMatch = void 0;
{
    msgPasswordDoesNotMatch = function(form) {
      let par = document.createElement('p');
      par.id = "message";
      let text = document.createTextNode('passwords do not match');
      par.appendChild(text);
      form.appendChild(par);
    }
}
var clearMessage = void 0;
{
    clearMessage = function () {
      var messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');
        if (messageDiv != null && typeof messageDiv !== 'undefined') {
       document.removeChild(messageDiv);
      }
    }
}
var hi = void 0;
{
    hi = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = this.form;
        var user = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        var cpassword = document.getElementById('cspassword').value;
        if (fieldsEmpty(user, email, password, cpassword)) {
            alert('no field can be left empty');
        }
        else if (!passwordMatch(password, cpassword)) {
            if (!msgPasswordDoesNotMatchDisplayed) {
                msgPasswordDoesNotMatch(form);
                msgPasswordDoesNotMatchDisplayed = true;
            }
        }
        else {
           clearMessage();
           alert('welcome');
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener('click', hi, false);
```