# Why does jQuery AJAX not hit success and error (ASP.NET Core)?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I have an action in my ASP.NET Core MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ImportDeviceAsAdmin(UserUploadDeviceVM userUploadDeviceVM)
{
    var uploadResult = await this.userService.UploadFilesAsync(userUploadDeviceVM.UserId, userUploadDeviceVM.Files);

    return uploadResult ? (IActionResult) Ok("success") : BadRequest("error");
}
```

and I have a piece of jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
        importUserFiles();
    });
});

function importUserFiles() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const userId = $("#user-emails-dropdown option:selected").val();

    formData.append("UserId", userId);

    const fileInput = $("#file-input")[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("Files", fileInput.files[i]);
    }

    importFileAjax(formData,
        function(response) { console.log(response); },
        function(response) { console.log(response); });
}

function importFileAjax(formData, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/ImportDeviceAsAdmin",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
    });
}
```

After I click a Submit button, my model goes to the specified action and the action works with it absolutely perfectly, no problem with it. But my jQuery AJAX call somehow hits neither `success` nor `error` statements. How can I fix it without specifying `async: false`? I have been trying all kinds of promises, async/await etc. from all the Internet but still couldn't fixed the error.

Part of my view with the Submit button:

```
<div id="file-uploader-container">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
                <label for="user-emails-dropdown">Select user</label>
                <div>
                    <select id="user-emails-dropdown" asp-items="ViewBag.Emails" asp-for="UserId">
                        <!-- there are user emails displayed-->
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="file-upload-button-container">
                <input id="file-input" name="Files" type="file" multiple />
            </div>
            <div class="file-upload-button-container">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see where you are canceling the `<form>` submit before doing the ajax call

Comment: @Taplar I don't understand you... In my form I didn't mentioned `asp-action` and `asp-controller` attributes, so without the JS the form cannot be submitted properly at all. Please correct me in the case I wrong.

Comment: If you click a submit button in a form, it will submit.  If no action or method is provided it will default to GET (i believe) and will submit to the same url as the page it is on

Comment: Ok, I'll check it, but don't the `form method="post"` does the trick?

Comment: So it will POST to the same url the form is on.  The point being, if you are not wanting to use a form in the traditional sense, you should consider changing your button from a submit to just a normal button, and prevent default on the form submit in case a user hits enter on one of the text or other inputs to generate a submit event.  Otherwise the form will submit and make the page transfer, killing the logic you are trying to do with the ajax

Comment: @Taplar did as you said, nothing changed at all: goes to action as expected, but doesn't hit `success` and `error`

Comment: What specifically did you change?

Comment: @Taplar I changed `submit` button to normal button with ID, and the target button of jQuery `click` event respectively

Comment: "normal button"?  `<input type="button">` ?

Comment: @Taplar yes, as you said, from `<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />` to `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button">Upload</button>`

Comment: No, that's not the same.  `<input type="submit">` === `<button>`  Both invoke form submits

Comment: @Taplar wow, it worked! But why `<input type="button">` does the job while `<button>` does not?

Comment: Of all three of those options, only type="button" does not generate a form submit.  You can put that on an input or a button, and the form submit would not happen.  Orginally `<input type="submit">` was the way to make a submit button for a form.  `<button>` was only added later as a more semantic form of that.

Comment: @Taplar yeas, thanks, already found an answer in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use, you can post your comment as the answer so I can +1 you if you want)