# which is better using <input type = submit> or <button>?

Tags: html, button, form-submit

I've been writing an HTML/PHP code that sends data using a Form.
I found that I can use `<button>` with ajax to send the data, or use `<input type= submit>` to do the same task.

I want to know which is better or preferable to use and why?

Comment: They do the same thing. Take your pick. And this question is an exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

**Function of both tag is same in the form with type attribute.**

```
<input type="submit" value="Post" />
<button type="submit">Post</button>
```

Comment: The button's default type is submit so there's no need to specify it.