# How to clear text field automatically when enter minus value

Tags: javascript

`

```
<input type="number" id="qty">
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add">

<script>
  function add(){
    qty = document.getElementById('qty').value
    if(qty>0){
        var tot = qty*25
        document.write(tot)
    
    }else{
        qty = ""
        alert("no")
    }
  }
</script>
```

'qty=""' is the correct way as mentioned on google. but not working for me.

Comment: document.getElementById("qty").value = "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
document.getElementById("qty").value = "";
```

and cast qty to number in your if

```
if(Number(qty) > 0)
```

Comment: Solved.Thankz dear. @King Julien XIII

Answer (score 0):

Values of inputs are always `string` , try this one in your condition :

```
if(Number(qty)>0){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to clear the input

```
qty.value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `qty = ''` isn't working is that you've assigned the string value of the input to that variable. Setting it to an empty string won't make the value of the input change - you need to explicitly change the element's value.

So, a few things first:

1. It's often useful to cache your elements first.
2. Remove the inline JS and replace it with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and attach it to the button element (a more modern approach).
3. [Use a `<button>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use) instead of an `<input type="button">`
4. Assign the total to an element's text content/innerText instead of `document.write` [for various reasons](https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2016/09/avoid-using-document-write-scripts-injection/).

Then when the handler is called coerce the string value of the input to a number, and use that in the condition. If the number is less than zero assign an empty string to the input value.

```js
// Cache the elements
const qty = document.querySelector('#qty');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a listener to the button
button.addEventListener('click', add);

function add() {

  // Coerce the input value to a number
  const val = Number(qty.value);

  if (val > 0) {

    // Instead of `document.write` assign
    // the total to the text content of an element
    result.textContent = val * 25;

  } else {

    // Set the value of the qty element to
    // an empty string
    qty.value = '';
    console.log('no');
  }
}
```

```css
#result { margin-top: 0.5em; }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="qty">
<button type="button">Add</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thankz for your valuable answer. @Andy

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check in time when you enter a value (as I understood from the question), you must have a listener on `<input type=" number" id="qty">` and event
'input'.  `qty.addEventListener('input', (e)=>{ // .... make your validation })`