# Can Blazor component interaction occur inside a Razor page form without causing a HTTP POST?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I have a requirement to create a form that accepts the following (hugely simplified) data model:

```
public class MyPost {
    public string MyTitle { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> Dates { get; set; } = new();
}
```

The challenge is that there can be many dates, and the user needs to generate them based on certain criteria (e.g. a "*one-off date*", or generate dates running "*every Wednesday until 30th December*", or any combination).  Therefore I need functionality within the form to allow the user to generate/view the dates before the form is finally submitted.

I'm new to .Net Core so please excuse my ignorance as I'm suffering tutorial overload.

### Problem summary

Hoping to use Blazor instead of JavaScript because of the neat date functionality in C#, I created a Blazor component to do this but any interaction (e.g. `@onclick`) triggers a HTTP Post in the parent Razor page which breaks everything.

**Is it possible therefore to interact with a Blazor component inside a Razor page form without triggering a form POST?**

### Example/research

Taking Microsoft's example of the counter component and simplifying it:

```
<p>Count: @currentCount</p>
<button @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

If this is then placed in a Razor (cshtml) page both inside and outside of a `<form>` tag I see totally different outcomes when interaction occurs.

```
<h3>Outside form tag</h3>
<Counter  />
<form method="post">
    <h3>Inside form tag</h3>
    <Counter />
</form>
```

- The component outside the form tag increments and I also see no network traffic in the analyzer (although I suspect SignalR may be the reason?).
- The component inside the form however triggers a page post when the `@onclick` event occurs.

[image]

Is it possible to use a component to create a dynamic Razor pages form, or does the entire form need to be moved within the component (the latter is a lot of work currently, hence the reason for this question before I do anything unnecessary)?

Comment: It seems that you wrote a WASM blazor app. In this case, you can execute POST with [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that button inside forms are handled as `type="submit"`. You should add `type="button"` to your actual button then it should work without a POST request.

```cs
<p>Count: @currentCount</p>
<button type="button" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  After years in the game I've never used the `button` tag, only `input type`.  I didn't even know `button type=button` was a thing.  For anyone else reading this, there's a nicely-explained answer discussing the differences at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079197/792888, or a full explanation at https://html.com/attributes/button-type/